# Auto refresh browser using server sent events

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, webhooks, server-sent-events

I am using a third party API to call a URL on my server when I receive a phone call.

I am trying to implement Server Sent Events in order to reload the browser when my URL is called by the API, however the page does not refresh when I do a POST test to the `api_new_call` function.

I am using PHP (codeigniter)

Javascript:

```
var source = new EventSource("/controller/new_call_trigger");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    location.reload();
};
```

Controller.php:

```
public function api_new_call() {
    $called_number = $this->input->post('called_number');
    $calling_number = $this->input->post('calling_number');
    $new_cad = $this->Model->api_new_cad($calling_number);
    $this->new_call_trigger();
}


public function new_call_trigger() {
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    echo "data: TEST";
    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this code

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo "data: TEST";
flush();
```

None of those headers refresh the page. You'll want to add this.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Add it above the `echo`, or else you'll have a headers already sent error.

Also, do a check for post, otherwise you'll get a redirect too many times error